# Closed subspace of $l_2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $$X=\{ a \in l_2 : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}a_n = 0} \}$$

> Show that X is not a closed subset of $l_2$

My general approach is to find a converging sequence $a_n \in X$, whose limit $a$ does not belong to $X$. Any hints to this problem as I fail to see what sequence I can construct here

Comment: So you're proving that $X$ is **not** a closed subset? The question is the opposite.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz That was a typo. I meant to write "is not a closed subset"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof, which assumes that the sum in the definition of $X$ has to converge absolutely.

The sequence $x\in l^2$ with $x_n = \frac1{\sqrt n\log n}$ has the property
that $\sum_n x_n \frac1{\sqrt n}=+\infty$.
Now let me 'double' this sequence, construct a sequence $y$ such that
$$
y_{2n+1}, \ y_{2n+2} \sim \frac1{\sqrt n\log n}
$$
and
$$
\frac{y_{2n+1}}{\sqrt{2n+1}} = -\frac{y_{2n+2}}{\sqrt{2n+2}},
$$
i.e.
$$
y_{2n+1}:= \frac1{\sqrt n\log n}, \ y_{2n+2}:=-\frac1{\sqrt n\log n} \frac{\sqrt{2n+2}}{\sqrt{2n+1}}.
$$
Then by construction
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{2m} y_n \frac1{\sqrt n}=0
$$
for all $m$. Hence
$$
y^m:=(y_1, \dots, y_{2m},0,\dots)
$$
is a sequence in $X$ such that $y^m \to y$ in $l^2$. But $y$ is not in $X$,
as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n\frac1{\sqrt n}$ does not converge absolutely. It does converge conditionally.

Answer (score -1):

There's a problem in the very definition of $X$. The sum $\sum n^{-1/2} a_n$ doesn't have to converge, for example it's infinite for $a_n = n^{-1/2} (\ln n)^{-1}$ (which still lies in $\ell_2$).

Once you fix the definition of $X$ (in one way or another), you should be able to construct a counterexample to closedness, based on the sequence $(a_n)$ given above.

Comment: You probably meant to write $a_n = n^{-1/2} (\ln n)^{-1}, n \ge 2$.

Comment: Exactly. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: I don't really see a problem in the definition of $X$ : I understand $X$ as the set of elements of $\ell_2$ such that $\sum n^{-1/2}a_n$ converges to $0$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I understand it also like that.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe That's the thing, you need to add an interpretation. Either "the series converges and the sum is zero", "the series converges absolutely and the sum is zero" or something else. The way it's written, the definition suggests that $\sum n^{-1/2} a_n$ is always a valid number that can be compared to zero - this is simply wrong.